# Why do I get a "ModuleNotFoundError" when running my app through a debugger even if package is installed and poetry venv is activated?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, python-poetry

I use VS Code, Pylama, and run my codes through a debugger.

The folder structure is as follows.

```
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── app
    │   ├── api
    │   ├── core
    │   │   ├── config.py
    │   │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   │   
    │   │   └── worker.py
    │   ├── crud
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── lib
    │   │   ├── be.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   ├── logger.py
    │   │   ├── omoi.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │        
    │   ├── main.py
```

The `main.py` is very simple and the linter doesn't complain about anything:

```
import argparse
import lib.logger
from core.config import settings
from core.worker import Worker


if __name__ == "main":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Basic Worker')
    parser.add_argument('--mode', type=str,
                        choices=['test', 'dummy', 'prod'],
                        default='prod')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    mode = args.mode
    main_worker = Worker()
    main_worker.start()
```

For the interpreter, I choose the one created by the `poetry shell` command. I confirmed both in the terminal of VS Code and at the bottom of the IDE:

```
service on main [✘!?] is  v0.1.0 via  v3.10.6 (service-v4nvssyk-py3.10)
```

Running the program from the terminal:

```
service/src# pyton main.py
```

works great.

But in debug mode of VS Code (F5), I always get an Exception:

```
ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'app'
  File "/home/me/service/src/app/lib/logger.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app.core.config import settings
  File "/home/me/service/src/app/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import lib.logger
```

Why?
The launch.json is:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: current file",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

The debug configuration should be:

```json
{
  "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: file corrente",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
            "env": { "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}/src"}
        }
    ]
}
```